# Delphi DLL Case Sensitivity

Tags: delphi, dll

I am writing a dll in delphi XE8 to be used by an app written in Delphi XE8.

My DLL looks like this.

```
  function GetInt : Integer; stdcall;
  begin
    Result := 300;
  end;
  exports GetInt;
```

My App looks like this.

```
dllHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar('myDLL.dll'));
  ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  if dllHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    @GetInt := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'GetInt');
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    if Assigned(GetInt) then
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetInt))
    else
      ShowMessage('Nope');
    end;
```

I get a "Specified Procedure could not be found" error. So I change my exports statement and my @GetInt statement from "**G**etInt" to "**g**etInt". Now everything is just fine.

So now my question: Why do my dll function and export need to be the same word with differing case sensitivity?

Comment: `GetProcAddress` **is** case-sensitive indeed. Your code looks correct. I suggest you to examine export directory of image (with e.g. `tdump`)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with presented code.

Comment: That's never a good sign.

Comment: I am using Delphi XE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows DLL exported symbol names are case sensitive. Your supplied code does not behave as you describe. Your actual code has mismatching letter case.

Almost certainly you are loading an out of date DLL.

Comment: Right. When my library has the function and the exports matching my app doesn't get the function. When I intentionally add the case mismatch my app loads the function (I change the app to reflect the dll exports statement)

Comment: That's not true. What you report is incorrect. You are loading an out of date DLL I guess.

Comment: THANK YOU! That is what was happening.